# Trivial inequality regarding complexity of conjugate gradient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, numerical-methods, computational-complexity, conjugate-gradient

I am reading [An Introduction to the Conjugate Gradient Method Without the Agonizing Pain](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient-figs.pdf). On page 20, the author wrote

> The convergence results for Steepest Descent are
>
> $$
> \lVert e_{(i)} \rVert_A \le \left(\frac{\kappa-1}{\kappa+1}\right)^i \lVert e_{(0)} \rVert_A
> $$

On page 37, the author points out that

> Suppose we wish to perform enough iterations to reduce the norm of the error by a factor of $\epsilon$; that is, $\lVert e_{(i)} \rVert_A \le \epsilon \lVert e_{(0)} \rVert_A$. Equation 28 can be used to show that the maximum number of iterations required to achieve this bound using Steepest Descent is
> $$
> i \le \left\lceil\frac{1}{2} \kappa \ln\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right) \right\rceil
> $$

This seems trivial but I cannot prove it. Here is my attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
\lVert e_{(i)} \rVert_A \le& \epsilon \lVert e_{(0)} \rVert_A \\
\left(\frac{\kappa-1}{\kappa+1}\right)^i \le& \epsilon \\
i \ln\left(\frac{\kappa-1}{\kappa+1}\right) \le& \ln \epsilon \\
i \ln\left(\frac{\kappa+1}{\kappa-1}\right) \ge& \ln \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right) \\
i \ge& \ln\left(\frac{\kappa+1}{\kappa-1}\right)^{-1} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)
\end{align}
$$

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [known lower bound for logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448162/why-does-frac2x2x-provide-a-particularly-tight-lower-bound-for-ln1x):
$$\ln(1 + x) \ge \frac{2x}{2 + x}, \forall x \ge 0. \tag{1}$$
Simply letting $x = \frac{2}{k - 1}$ in (1), we have
$$\ln\frac{k+1}{k-1} \ge \frac{2}{k}.$$

Then we have
$$\left(\ln\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)^{-1}\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon} \le \frac{k}{2}\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}.$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing the lower bound out! However, I believe there is some confusion between $\le$ and $\ge$. The paper says $i \le ...$, which is very likely a typo because $\lVert e_{(i)} \rVert_A \le \epsilon \lVert e_{(0)} \rVert_A$ clearly requires a lower bound on $i$, not an upper bound. As a result, what we need is a lower bound on $\left(\ln\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)^{-1}$, or equivalently an upper bound on $\ln\frac{k+1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @nalzok Yes, it is confusing. We require $i \ge \left(\ln\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)^{-1}\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. What I got is that the optimal $i$ does not exceed $\lceil \frac{k}{2}\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon} \rceil$.

Comment: This is true, and in the author's defense, when $\kappa \to \infty$ we have $\left(\ln\frac{\kappa+1}{\kappa-1}\right)^{-1} \approx \frac{\kappa}{2}.$